# Does vulkan has the maximum number limits of logic device creation?

Tags: c++, nvidia, vulkan

I wrote the following code to test the maximum logic device number.

```
#include "vulkan/vulkan.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<vk::Instance> instances;
    std::vector<vk::Device>   devices;

    try {

        for( ; true; ) {

            vk::InstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo {};
            instances.push_back( vk::createInstance( instanceInfo ) );

            auto physicalDevices = instances.back().enumeratePhysicalDevices();
            if( 0 == physicalDevices.size() )
                return 0;

            vk::DeviceQueueCreateInfo deviceQueueCreateInfo {};
            deviceQueueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = 0;
            deviceQueueCreateInfo.queueCount = 1;

            vk::DeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo {};
            deviceCreateInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
            deviceCreateInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &deviceQueueCreateInfo;
            auto device = physicalDevices.front().createDevice( deviceCreateInfo );
            if( !device ) {
                throw 0;
            }
            devices.push_back( device );
        }
    }
    catch( std::system_error e ) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl
            << e.code() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( ... ) {
    }

    for( auto device : devices )
        device.destroy();
    for( auto instance : instances )
        instance.destroy();
    printf( "Maximum device is %d\n", devices.size() );
    return static_cast<int>( devices.size() );
}
```

The following is my test results:
Windows 10 64bit  8G  RAM GTX 750Ti:   Maximum device is 42,
Ubuntu            8G  RAM GTX 750Ti:   Maximum device is 63,
Windows 10 64bit  16G RAM GTX 1080:    Maximum device is 42,
Ubuntu            64G RAM Titan X:     Maximum device is 31,

The test results show that the vulkan has the maximum number limits of logic device creation, and the limits may vary according to the operating system. I don't find any document about the limits, is there any way to get this limits ? Another question, if i want run a large number of vulkan applications on a server, how can i overcome this limits ?

Comment: "*if i want run a large number of vulkan applications on a server, how can i overcome this limits ?*" To what end, exactly? Unless the server has multiple GPUs, I'm not really sure what the point of that is. Each device will have to share computing resources with every other device. It'd probably be more efficient to have a single process with a single device, and farm jobs out to it, allowing it to decide how many resources to give to each one.

Comment: It should also be noted that your code tests the *instance* count as well, not just the number of logical devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Vulkan spec only says this:

> Multiple logical devices can be created from the same physical device. Logical device creation may fail due to lack of device-specific resources (in addition to the other errors). If that occurs, vkCreateDevice will return VK_ERROR_TOO_MANY_OBJECTS.

So the number of devices you can create is limited (obviously, since each one must use *some* resources, and all resources are finite), but the number is implementation-dependent.

The Vulkan conformance tests require that you are able to [create at least five devices](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS/blob/master/external/vulkancts/modules/vulkan/api/vktApiDeviceInitializationTests.cpp#L397).

It's possible that some of the resources being used are per-process rather than system-wide. Have you tried spawning a bunch of processes, each of which creates a single VkDevice?

But failing that: your only option is to use a different implementation with a higher limit, or lobby the hardware vendor to use less resources per device (or whatever) to support a higher limit.